# Why does the 'Barbie' (2023) opening scene pay homage to '2001: A Space Odyssey'?

Tags: reference, 2001-a-space-odyssey, barbie

In the 2023 *Barbie* movie, the opening scene strikingly resembles the iconic beginning of Stanley Kubrick's *2001: A Space Odyssey*. What is the significance or intention behind this similarity?

Comment: Note that in 2001, the monolith is a tall, mysterious artifact that greatly changes the course of development of the proto-humans that discover it; The Barbie movie is suggesting that Barbie dolls had/have a similarly profound effect on the development of the little girls who discover them.

Comment: When in fact it's the reverse.

Comment: How about "had a similarly profound effect *on the realm of commercial doll toys*"

Comment: plus, as well as just suggesting a profound transition, this frames the state of affairs before the transition as pre-historically primitive, which is a commentary on the world of dolls before Barbie. The transformation was not just like that from early humans to something incrementally better, but comparable to the very moment when animals made a discontinuous transformation, to became human.

Comment: @user103041 “profound” does not mean “positive”

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Three main Kubrick references are deliberately woven into the fabric of Barbie’s visual identity, drawn from the Kubrick classics: 2001: A Space Odyssey, The Shining and Dr. Strangelove.
>
> **According to Gerwig, each instance serves more than just a humorous nod to the legendary director – they play a vital part in the film’s narrative, aesthetic and overall ethos, contributing to her uniquely quirky cinematic style.**
>
> Far from being mere parodic imitations, Gerwig insisted on the meticulous execution of these references. “I thought, ‘I want to do it only if we can do it’. **I want to do it with front-screen projection**; I want to **do it with the original plates**; I want to build the sets as they built it – like, let’s make it count,” she said during the podcast, referring to the conversations she had with her production team about **accurately recreating some of the most iconic and innovative visionary aspects of 2001.**
>
> The high standards set by Gerwig for these references directly **echo the perfectionism Kubrick was famous for**, imbuing the project with a **unique charm and unexpected depth**. “***The only way it can be funny to me is if it’s executed with the utmost integrity and excellence. Then it becomes both a funny idea and something more***,” she stated.
>
> “It just felt like, what a fun thing to transpose – with respect – to this doll.”
>
> https://faroutmagazine.co.uk/greta-gerwig-stanley-kubrick-references-barbie/

So rather than just a lazy homage, or parody, she felt that she was honoring it by going to a greater effort than normally required to achieve the effect she wanted.
The take-out, if you will, is that Gerwig thought Kubrick represented the masculine in film-making, and she wanted to replace that with her type of film-making, replacing the masculinity with dolls, for her, that is turning it on its head, rather than just a cheap knock-off.

> “I remember her saying, ‘What would Kubrick do if he were alive today?” production VFX supervisor Glenn Pratt of Framestore told IndieWire. “And she very much was of the opinion — I think quite rightly — that he would’ve embraced that LED Volume as a tool to give you that small, nuanced, interactive lighting, which gives more complex results.”

[image]

Shooting set.

> “**I ended up talking it through with my therapist, and she thought it was hilarious**.” Greta Gerwig reveals why she decided to open “Barbie” with that glorious Stanley Kubrick reference

https://www.tiktok.com/@cinemablend/video/7272855711254646058

Most interviews have the same set of quotes:

> [Kubrick]’s entire filmography is just staggering, but he’s also the paragon of a certain type of **masculine filmmaking**, and it just felt like what a fun thing to do to sort of **transpose with respect to this doll**. I did have a moment of like, ‘am I really going to start this movie with a 2001 parody?’ But I ended up talking it through with my therapist and she thought it was hilarious.

Additional images of Barbie shot in the Volume, in V stage, Leavesden Studios (Warner Bros. Studios):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the therapist get any credits in the movie?

Comment: either a 'thanks' or a NDA via the legal dept. :P

Comment: "_I want to do it with front-screen projection"_ - I wonder if they did wind up using the exact same method that Kubrick did. It was fairly complicated, using a special 3M reflective screen which would have required that the powerful light source be located in the camera lens, which of course was impossible, they got around that by pointing the camera into a nearby mirror positioned at a specific angle. "_I want to do it with the original plates"_ - I assume she means the glass plates containing the still images made in Africa. I wonder if they were able to borrow them for the production?

Comment: @StevePemberton no, IIRC, they had issues with the plates and did their own version. They used the V stage at Leavesden Studios (aka Warner Bros. studios) to shoot it in the Volume LED set instead. Seems they dropped the plates idea anyway and went their own way - sticking to the plates would have caused more complications than was necessary for what they were doing

Comment: I imagine with tech like Volume etc available, it is unlikely anyone would go back to how Kubrick actually did it. A lot of what you do, isn't because you want to do it, it is because of limitations of the day. You do what you have to, to get the shot across, and if that is difficult, you design the shot so that it is less difficult to get done, but still get the idea of the shot across. FP, RP, sausage machines, cut-outs on glass, pretty much not an ideal scenario anymore. SK plates would have been nice to see up on the Volume though, I imagine they tried that at least.

Comment: But that's not what she said, she said she wanted to recreate Kubrick's methods, not just make something visually similar. In the end all they did was make a similar looking set and backdrop, which is fine but no need for her to go on about ,"I want to do it only if we can do it" as if they went to whatever lengths necessary to recreate what Kubrick did, which they didn't, which is quite apparent if you put them side by side. Does it matter that it looks different? No. Do audiences care that they didn't recreate Kubrick? No. But there's no need for her to claim or at least imply that they did.

Comment: @StevePemberton oh i agree, what shes been quoted as saying, and repeated often, is not what happened, or at least been truncated: the first, her intention, possibly before some sort of discussion with the crew; and then the reality of what happened after (such a discussion, that ends with no, you're not going to be doing it Kubrick's way), resulting in something, that as you can see from the set, results in just modern day standard method, and then saying kubrick would've done it this way too...

Comment: Seems to be common for someone, who doesn't do the actual work, to claim something, only to find out that those (who do the actual work), protest or say no it can't be done. Usually results in a slightly messed up shoot that has to be fixed in post. Apparently the 2001 shoot needed fixing from strobing leds, which surprised me...

Comment: I had thought of that, if the interview had been prior to production. But since (I think) it was afterwards, what likely happened is she initially had an enthusiastic ambitious idea to duplicate Kubrick, then later found out how hard it would be, and then backpedaled on "I want to do it only if we can do it" and instead went with a "good enough" more cost effective method. But then she didn't want to give up the impressiveness that comes with recreating Kubrick, after all less than 1/1000th of a percent will know they didn't actually. Rationalizing it with Stanley would have done it this way.

Comment: What would have been nice is if she had said something like, "I wanted to do it justice and be meticulous. At the beginning I even intended to use the exact same methods that Stanley Kubrick had used, front screen projection, even using the original glass plates. But when we looked at it we found out just how hard what they did was. I gained new appreciation for what he accomplished with the technology that he had to work with. But in the end we were able to duplicate it pretty closely using more modern methods."

Comment: Agreed, but you're right too, a lot of people would just never notice nor even care.

Comment: Yes, that is true, he would uave been able to achieve a lot more in terms of shots and visuals. Many shots on 2001 would have been dictated by technical limitations of the day

Comment: He probably would have loved how much and how accessible the editing process is today